# How to "make and program" my PIC32 without using MPLAB?

Tags: hex, pic, mplab, flash-memory

I have to find some solution to flash my Program Memory into my PIC32 without MPLab.

I think the first step is to generate the .hex file from the source code.
And the second one, flashing the memory into the PIC.

How can I do it using a standard IDE or command line please ?
(Currently using MPLab, I use the MPLab Snap to flash the program memory)

Comment: MPLAB X contains a bunch of utilities that can be run standalone including their own compiler, make and a flashing utility. Where those are located you need to find out for yourself it has been a while.

Comment: Try the NSDSP-1-3V3 from [Northern Software](https://www.northernsoftware.com/nsdsp/). It installs about a million times faster than MPLABX and comes with command line utilities. Linux versions are also available.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do command line compilation in a docker image this for a PIC24 micro. My guess is it may be similar on a PIC-32, but I have not tested it.

My docker image contains an ubuntu image the xc16 compiler, and mplabx install. The binary folders of mplabx and xc16 are added to PATH. Then I can compile with this inside the project folder:

```
  prjMakefilesGenerator.sh . &&
  make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
```

prjMakefilesGenerator.sh has a Windows counterpart so it should be possible to do something like this in Powershell or cmd, I guess. I think prjMakefilesGenerator is what mplabx runs to generate the make files it uses when running make. In This case, make is the binary that comes bundled with Mplabx but my guess is regular Linux make would also do the job. During build more binaries from mplabx install are called and I have not taken the time to separate out what is strictly needed and what is not.